# How to decrease the font size in dial charts

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using jfreechart to plot dial charts, and I want to decrease the font size.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

I use jfreechart to generate a dial image for a monitor and there are three different fonts on it.

[image]

1. The title font.
2. The dial ticks font.
3. The "legend" font at the bottom of the dial, referred to as the DialTextAnnotation.

Not sure which one you're looking for so I'll outline each one.
Just looking at my code that generates this (it's in groovy) here's the procedure for each:

### Title

Use the main class `JFreeChart`'s method `setTitle(java.awt.Font font)` method.
The font can be sized in the constructor.

```
// Set the title font to bold SansSerif size 12.
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(myplot);
chart.setTitle(
   new org.jfree.chart.title.TextTitle("The title",
       new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12)
   );
);
```

### Annotation

```
// Set the annotation font to bold Dialog size 8
DialTextAnnotation annotation = new DialTextAnnotation("My Annotation Text");
annotation.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 8));
// Add to the plot
myplot.addLayer(annotation);
```

### Dial Ticks

```
// Create the dial scale
StandardDialScale scale = new StandardDialScale(.......
// Set the dial font to plain dialog size 14
scale.setTickLabelFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 14));
```